# When I add a bit of code, the rest stops working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Details:**
I'm programming a discord.py bot for my server and I wanted to add some commands for the python shell that could send messages via console.

**Problem:**
When I added this code, it worked fine but the code I had before stopped working.
It would be a big help if you could tell me what I had wrong and how to fix it, my code is below

```
import discord
import time

client = discord.Client()
prefix = 'c!'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

#spam command
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + 'spam'):
        if message.author == client.get_user(int(477483580918857755)):
            victim = str(message.content)
            victim = victim.replace(prefix + 'spam ', '')
            victim = victim.replace('<@!', '')
            victim = victim.replace('>','')
            user = client.get_user(int(victim))
            await message.channel.send("Now spamming " + user.name)
            await user.send('Automated spam session from ' + message.author.name)
            t = time.localtime()
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
            await channel.send(LogMsg)

            for i in range(5):
                await user.send("spam")
            
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use that command!')
            await message.channel.send('Please contact wharncliff1 if you think this is a mistake')
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            t = time.localtime()
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
            await channel.send(LogMsg)
    
#help command
    elif message.content.startswith(prefix + 'help'):
        
        embed=discord.Embed(title="CliffBot Command List", description="List of commands for " + client.user.name)
        embed.add_field(name="Boop Command", value="Syntax - `" + prefix + "boop <user>`", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Help Command", value="Syntax - `" + prefix + "help`", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Help command summoned by " + message.author.name)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

        t = time.localtime()
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
        channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
        LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
        await channel.send(LogMsg)


#boop command
    elif message.content.startswith(prefix + "boop"):
        victim = str(message.content)
        print(str(victim))
        victim = victim.replace(prefix + 'boop ', '')
        victim = victim.replace('<@', '')
        victim = victim.replace('!', '')
        victim = victim.replace('>','')
        print(str(victim))
        user = client.get_user(int(victim))
        if str(message.author) == str(user):
            await message.channel.send('No! I will not allow you to boop yourself!')
            t = time.localtime()
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
            await channel.send(LogMsg)

        else:
            await message.channel.send("Booped " + user.name)
            await user.send('**Boop!**')
            t = time.localtime()
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
            await channel.send(LogMsg)

#super boop command
    elif message.content.startswith(prefix + "super-boop"):
        victim = str(message.content)
        victim = victim.replace(prefix + 'super-boop ', '')
        victim = victim.replace('<@', '')
        victim = victim.replace('!', '')
        victim = victim.replace('>','')
        if str(message.author) == str(user):
            await message.channel.send('No! I will not allow you to boop yourself!')
            t = time.localtime()
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
            await channel.send(LogMsg)

        else:
            await message.channel.send("Super-Booped " + user.name)
            t = time.localtime()
            current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
            channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
            LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
            await channel.send(LogMsg)
            
            for i in range(10):
                await user.send('**Boop!**')
    

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print('USER ID: ' + str(client.user.id))
    print('')
    print('To Open the Console, type ' + prefix + 'console in the shell')
    print('------')

    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='Do ' + prefix + 'help!'))

#Console Commands
#When i add all this set of commands below, all the above stops working

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    x = int(1)
    console = str(prefix + 'console')
    while x == 1:
        ConsoleInput = input('')
        if ConsoleInput == console:
            while x == 1:
                print('------')
                print('Please Select a Module')
                print('1 - Enable/Disable Commands')
                print('2 - Announce')
                print('3 - COMING SOON')
                print('99 - Exit Console')
                print('------')
                ConsoleInput = int(input(''))
                
                #Enable/Disable Commands
                if ConsoleInput == 1:
                    print('------')
                    print('Module 1 Selected - Enable/Disable Commands')
                    print('Status: IN PROGRAMMING')

                #Announce
                elif ConsoleInput == 2:
                    print('------')
                    print('Module 2 Selected - Announce')
                    print("What's the id of the channel you want to announce in?")
                    Channel_id = int(input())
                    print("Embed? (1 for yes, 2 for no)")
                    YeNo = int(input())
                    
                    if YeNo == 1:
                        print("What is the Title for the Embed message?")
                        EmbedTitle = str(input())
                        print("What is the Description for the Embed message?")
                        announcement = str(input())
                        print('Announcing')
                        channel = client.get_channel(Channel_id)
                        embed=discord.Embed(title=EmbedTitle, description=announcement, color=0xff40ff)
                        await channel.send(embed=embed)
                        print("Announced")

                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
                        await channel.send('`' + current_time + '` ' + 'Console User used command in Console ' '`' + str(Channel_id) + ' ' + EmbedTitle + ' ' + announcement + ' ' + str(YeNo) + '`')
                        
                    elif YeNo == 2:
                        print("What is the announcement?")
                        announcement = str(input())
                        print("Announcing")
                        channel = client.get_channel(Channel_id)
                        await channel.send(announcement)
                        print("Announced")
                        
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
                        await channel.send('`' + current_time + '` ' + 'Console User used command in Console ' '`' + str(Channel_id) + ' ' + announcement + ' ' + str(YeNo) + '`')
                        
                    
                elif ConsoleInput == 3:
                    print('------')
                    print('Module 3 Selected - COMING SOON')

                #69 cause why not
                elif ConsoleInput == 69:
                    print('------')
                    print('nice')

                #Exit Console
                elif ConsoleInput == 99:
                    print('------')
                    print('Exiting Console')
                    print('You can restart the console by typing ' + prefix + 'console in the shell')
                    print('------')
                    break
                else:
                    print('------')
                    print('That was not an option!')
            

client.run('NzUwNjg1NTY4ODk1Mjg3Mjk3.X0-Iag.HmGd4NmTS-WwYgj40cWrSQpGao0')
```

**NOTE -**  I already reset my token.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  "Stopped working" is not a problem description.  Where does execution get?  Where does it stop?  Which intermediate values are surprises to you?  What is the difference with the working version?  What is so complex about your code dependencies that it *requires* 200 lines of code to demonstrate?

Comment: @Prune Sorry, as I said I'm new to this, ill repost with more detail and with the correct MRE

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
That's why we have the intro tour.

Comment: @Prune Here's my updates post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188405/discord-py-bot-stops-responding-after-i-add-a-new-block-of-code

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a repeated names problem and an user input problem. After testing with two repeated `on_ready` async functions, discord.py seems to break, or doesn't have anything to handle the repeated `on_ready` functions.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print('USER ID: ' + str(client.user.id))
    # the rest of the code from the first on_ready function

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    x = int(1)
    console = str(prefix + 'console')
    # the rest of the code from the second on_ready function
```

This can be fixed easily by combining the two `on_ready` functions.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print('USER ID: ' + str(client.user.id))
    # the rest of the code from the first on_ready function

    c def on_ready():
    x = int(1)
    console = str(prefix + 'console')
    # the rest of the code from the sencond on_ready function
```

However from your code, it looks like you have some user inputs that are needed for your console commands. In python whenever you are asking for an input, the console/code will pause until the user entered an input. You might need to use asyncio to fix this problem. Or the best way to do it is to make 2 separate bot files one is for console commands, and the other is for discord commands.