# discord.py bot stops responding after I add a new block of code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im new to python and discord.py, this is a repost with updated details and without the block of code that was hard to understand. I have not found an answer to this problem online so it is probably a small mistake on my end.

**Problem**
I am trying to program a discord.py bot for my server which can do some basic commands.
I wanted to add some functionality into the shell which could allow me to control the bot via python shell.
Before this, I had some basic commands which would work as expected (I do c!help and it responds with an embed message with help)
After I added the code for control via the console, the commands for discord stopped responding as intended.

Desired Behaviour: I type c!boop {user} in discord, The bot send a dm to said user and a logging message is sent in the logging channel. I do c!console in the python shell, my interactive menu comes up

What Happens: I type c!boop {user} in discord, I get nothing back. I do c!console in the python shell, my interactive menu comes up.

As I said, It worked before I added the new code for the Shell.

**My Code**
The code here has been shortened a lot for the MRE but if you think the full code would be necessary, just ask. Sorry if it still is long, I already removed 3/4 of it to only keep the parts relevant to my problem.

```
import discord
import time

client = discord.Client()
prefix = 'c!'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
#This bit is the command for within discord
    if message.content.startswith(prefix + "boop"):
        
        #Getting the Victim's user id
        victim = str(message.content)
        victim = victim.replace(prefix + 'boop ', '')
        victim = victim.replace('<@', '')
        victim = victim.replace('!', '')
        victim = victim.replace('>','')
        
        #Booping the user
        user = client.get_user(int(victim))
        await message.channel.send("Booped " + user.name)
        await user.send('**Boop!**')
        t = time.localtime()
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
        channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
        LogMsg = str('`' + current_time + '` ' + message.author.name + ' used command in ' + str(message.channel) + ' `' + message.content + '`')
        await channel.send(LogMsg)


#After I added this section, the above command stopped working
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print('USER ID: ' + str(client.user.id))
    print('')
    print('To Open the Console, type ' + prefix + 'console in the shell')
    print('------')

    console = str(prefix + 'console')
    while 1 == 1:
        ConsoleInput = input('')
        if ConsoleInput == console:
            while 1 == 1:
                print('------')
                print('Please Select a Module')
                print('1 - Announce')
                print('99 - Exit Console')
                print('------')
                ConsoleInput = int(input(''))

                if ConsoleInput == 1:
                    print('------')
                    print('Module 1 Selected - Announce')
                    print("What's the id of the channel you want to announce in?")
                    Channel_id = int(input())
                    print("Embed? (1 for yes, 2 for no)")
                    YeNo = int(input())
                    
                    if YeNo == 1:
                        print("What is the Title for the Embed message?")
                        EmbedTitle = str(input())
                        print("What is the Description for the Embed message?")
                        announcement = str(input())
                        print('Announcing')
                        channel = client.get_channel(Channel_id)
                        embed=discord.Embed(title=EmbedTitle, description=announcement, color=0xff40ff)
                        await channel.send(embed=embed)
                        print("Announced")

                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
                        await channel.send('`' + current_time + '` ' + 'Console User used command in Console ' '`' + str(Channel_id) + ' ' + EmbedTitle + ' ' + announcement + ' ' + str(YeNo) + '`')
                        
                    elif YeNo == 2:
                        print("What is the announcement?")
                        announcement = str(input())
                        print("Announcing")
                        channel = client.get_channel(Channel_id)
                        await channel.send(announcement)
                        print("Announced")
                        
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        channel = client.get_channel(int(759798825161326593))
                        await channel.send('`' + current_time + '` ' + 'Console User used command in Console ' '`' + str(Channel_id) + ' ' + announcement + ' ' + str(YeNo) + '`')

                elif ConsoleInput == 99:
                    print('------')
                    print('Exiting Console')
                    print('You can restart the console by typing ' + prefix + 'console in the shell')
                    print('------')
                    break

client.run(TOKEN GOES HERE)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Blocking code

It appears that the synchronous code in the `on_ready` event is what is hanging the bot; waiting for input from the console halts any other code from running, including reacting to commands.

The only way to fix this is to design your announcement command in a different way that doesn't involve using your console, such as having it be a command for your bot.

#### Sidenote about `discord.Client()`

Since you're using the lower-level API (`discord.Client`), you may find it more difficult to develop new commands for your bot. I would recommend using the [bot commands framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html) (`discord.ext.commands`) that discord.py comes packaged with. The pitch is in the link so instead, here's an example using the framework with your boop command:

```
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

prefix = 'c!'
TOKEN = ''

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as', client.user.name)

@client.command(name='boop')
async def client_boop(ctx, user: discord.User):
    """Boops a user.
Accepted inputs are: ID, mention, name#discrim, or name
Example: c!boop thegamecracks"""
    await user.send('**Boop!**')
    await ctx.channel.send("Booped " + user.name)

    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    log_channel = client.get_channel(759798825161326593)
    LogMsg = '`{}` {} used command in {} `{}`'.format(
        current_time,
        ctx.author.name,
        ctx.channel.name,
        ctx.message.content
    )
    await log_channel.send(LogMsg)

client.run(TOKEN)
```